# error in installation on 16.04 from both Synaptic and command line

Tags: software-installation

I installed the Gnome 3.20 upgrade by using the command line steps recommended in the email from Ubuntu. This install resulted in the reported failure but the system now reports Gnome 3.20 level. Since then, both command line and Synaptic Package Manager return this error. Software Install never worked and since I already used Synaptic on 12.04 and 14.04 I have ignored it.(it still doesn't work) I traced down the error message it returns and they are as follows:

```
Job for amavis.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status amavis.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript amavis, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package amavisd-new (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up bleachbit (1.10-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 amavisd-new
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
Setting up amavisd-new (1:2.10.1-2ubuntu1) ...
Creating/updating amavis user account...
Job for amavis.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status amavis.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript amavis, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package amavisd-new (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 amavisd-new

=>"systemctl status amavis.service" returned:

● amavis.service - LSB: Starts amavisd-new mailfilter
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/amavis; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-08-25 09:32:19 PDT; 7min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 8672 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/amavis start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 25 09:32:19 dsd-Aspire-7250 amavis[8672]:   The value of variable $myhostname is "dsd-Aspire-7250", but should have been
Aug 25 09:32:19 dsd-Aspire-7250 amavis[8672]:   a fully qualified domain name; perhaps uname(3) did not provide such.
Aug 25 09:32:19 dsd-Aspire-7250 amavis[8672]:   You must explicitly assign a FQDN of this host to variable $myhostname
Aug 25 09:32:19 dsd-Aspire-7250 amavis[8672]:   in /etc/amavis/conf.d/05-node_id, or fix what uname(3) provides as a host's
Aug 25 09:32:19 dsd-Aspire-7250 amavis[8672]:   network name!
Aug 25 09:32:19 dsd-Aspire-7250 amavis[8672]: (failed).
Aug 25 09:32:19 dsd-Aspire-7250 systemd[1]: amavis.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 25 09:32:19 dsd-Aspire-7250 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Starts amavisd-new mailfilter.
Aug 25 09:32:19 dsd-Aspire-7250 systemd[1]: amavis.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 25 09:32:19 dsd-Aspire-7250 systemd[1]: amavis.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
~
~
=>"journalctl -xe"returned:

Aug 25 09:43:05 dsd-Aspire-7250 .My-Weather-Indicator.desktop[7292]: --- Updating data in location 0 ---
Aug 25 09:43:05 dsd-Aspire-7250 .My-Weather-Indicator.desktop[7292]: ****** Updating weather
Aug 25 09:43:05 dsd-Aspire-7250 .My-Weather-Indicator.desktop[7292]: ****** Calculating rawOffset
Aug 25 09:43:05 dsd-Aspire-7250 .My-Weather-Indicator.desktop[7292]: Bug #1568774 Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is 
Aug 25 09:43:05 dsd-Aspire-7250 .My-Weather-Indicator.desktop[7292]: ****** Updated weather
Aug 25 09:43:05 dsd-Aspire-7250 .My-Weather-Indicator.desktop[7292]: {'current_conditions': {'precip_today': None, 'dawn_time': '05:31'
Aug 25 09:43:05 dsd-Aspire-7250 .My-Weather-Indicator.desktop[7292]: : None, 'moon_icon': 'mwi-moon22.png', 'avehumidity': None, 'condi
Aug 25 09:43:11 dsd-Aspire-7250 nemo-autostart.desktop[7309]: (nemo:7309): Gtk-WARNING **: Allocating size to GtkGrid 0x1a39ae0 without
Aug 25 09:43:34 dsd-Aspire-7250 systemd[2997]: Time has been changed
-- Subject: Time change
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- The system clock has been changed to REALTIME microseconds after January 1st, 1970.
Aug 25 09:43:34 dsd-Aspire-7250 systemd[1]: Time has been changed
-- Subject: Time change
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- The system clock has been changed to REALTIME microseconds after January 1st, 1970.
Aug 25 09:43:34 dsd-Aspire-7250 systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 10h 40min 22.323453s random time.
Aug 25 09:43:34 dsd-Aspire-7250 systemd[1]: snapd.refresh.timer: Adding 5h 8min 7.468582s random time.
Aug 25 09:43:34 dsd-Aspire-7250 systemd-timesyncd[1284]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.91.157:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
lines 1573-1595/1595 (END)
```

One further note: all software seems to work okay after installation but I still receive the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is a bit confusing, it took me quite a bit figuring out what it means. Based on @Tsakiroglou's answer, you edit the the file

`/etc/amavis/conf.d/05-node_id`

Towards the end, there is a line commented out:

`\# $myhostname = mail.example.com`

Uncomment this line and direct to the FQDN that Postfix is listening.

Answer (score 0):

I am back , having a descent pc in front of me to post normal-structured answer.Allow me to post for future help.

First of all Synaptic package manager or apt has to be cleared.Everytime a package breaks you have to clear apt manager , here you would have to clear with $sudo apt remove amavisd-new.
This is the one way indeed.To remove amavis  , pick a proper(fqdn) hostname and install it again.

The second way and simpliest is not to remove the package just to fix this.
Edit /etc/amavis/conf.d/05-node_id.

```
sudo nano /etc/amavis/conf.d/05-node_id
```

If you dont have nano , use another editor.
Find line #$myhostname delete # to uncomment the line and change to `$myhostname = ubuntuServe.example.com` //ubuntuServer is the hostname you get after $hostname command.
Restart Amavisd

```
sudo systemctl restart amavis.service
```

and it should work.

PS:I experienced this situation trying to set up amavisd-new package at a mail server (postfix) in a ubuntu server installation.
In this case where the whole situation mess up after just an upgrade of gnome it would be wise just to remove the package and install it again after the update.
Please accept my apologies for my previous mess-like answer.